# Apply as alias with Arel to ActiveRecord of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, activerecord, arel

My Rails project uses PostgreSQL. It got some problems on alias "**as**" with Arel.

This one works.

```
Member.select(:id, Member.arel_table[:name].as("identity"))
```

It gets data correctly.

```
Member.select(:id, Member.arel_table[:name].as("identity")).first["identity"] #=> 'John'
```

**Issue 1**

When it comes to **count** methods, it fails.

```
Member.select(:id, Member.arel_table[:name].as("identity")).count
```

Error:

```
: SELECT COUNT(id, #<Arel::Nodes::As:0x0000000988a9b0>) FROM "members"
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "As"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(id, #<Arel::Nodes::As:0x0000000988a9b0>) FROM "...
```

**Issue 2**

If alias "**as**" with space, it is not quoted.

```
Member.select(:id, Member.arel_table[:name].as("long name"))
```

Error

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "name"
```

LINE 1: ...ECT  "members"."id", "members"."name" AS long name FROM ...

If the alias is quoted, it works again

```
Member.select(:id, Member.arel_table[:name].as("\"long name\""))
```

Is this a potential cause of SQL injection?

What is the correct way to use alias as in Arel over PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

why not just use alias_attribute in your Member model?

Add `alias_attribute :long_name, :name` and then you can use `Member.select(:id, :long_name)`

Here's sample, tested:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  alias_attribute :stack_name, :username

[142] pry(main)> User.select(:id, :stack_name)
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users"."id", "users"."username" FROM "users"
=> [#<User:0x0000000a027628 id: 1, username: "developer">,
 #<User:0x0000000a0274c0 id: 2, username: "Swistak">]
[143] pry(main)> _.first.stack_name
=> "developer"
```